# Condição que verifique o registo

Tags: php

Tenho de criar uma condição para verificar a inserção de um registo.
Nessa inserção tenho `dois inputs type radio`, um com `value="Ok"` e  outro com `value="Não Ok"`:

```
$tabela1 .= '<td style="float:center"> <input type="radio" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Ok" required></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td style="float:center"> <input type="radio" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Não Ok" required></td>';
```

Quando insiro o registo na tabela da base de dados, insere 23 linhas. Ao inserir as 23 linhas pretendo criar um `if` que verifique, caso exista numa das linhas ao inserir com `value="Não Ok"` então a condição seja `true`, caso nas 23 linhas receba o `value="Ok"` então a condição é `false`.

Estou a fazer desta forma mas não está a funcionar:

```
if($sim != "Ok"){
....
}else{
....
}
```

Desta forma, receba em todas as 23 linhas `value="Ok"` ou numa ou mais linhas receba o `value="Não Ok"` a condição é sempre `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro que no seu `HTML` o `name` esta com S maiúsculo e no php está minusculo, não sei se tem algum problema, mas é bom deixar os dois iguais.

```
$tabela1 .= '<td style="float:center"> <input type="radio" name= "sim['.$y.']" value="Ok" required></td>';
```

No PHP verifique se em algum dos inputs esta marcado como "Não OK", caso esteja defina uma variável apenas para checar isso, e depois faça a verificação em cima dessa variável.

```
$res = false;
if($Sim == "Não Ok"){
    $res = true;
}
```

No próximo if:

```
if($res){
    //Não OK
}else{
    //OK
}
```

Comment: dessa forma tanto coloque `if(in_array("OK", $sim)){` ou `if(in_array("Não OK", $sim)){` envia sempre o que está dentro do `else`

Comment: Utilize sendo case sensitive, acabei de perceber que no value esta `Ok` e no if esta `OK`, vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: estou a fazer a condição if depois de fechar o `for`para enviar tudo só num email, porque se for dentro do `for`envia um email por linha. Será por isso que depois não consegue verificar o `array`

Comment: Cara, sem ver o código completo fica meio difícil, mas seu array `$sim` está recebendo no HTML uma variável (Imagino que seja contadora) dentro dos colchetes, então você precisa verificar como está a estrutura do seu array, pois se a variável `$i` está imprimindo `1` por exemplo, no if você usaria `in_array("Ok", $sim[1])`

Comment: podemos continuar a falar no chat?

Comment: Podemos, mas em vez disso sugiro você editar sua pergunta com o código completo e o valor do array (utilizar um `var_dump($sim)`) para que outras pessoas possam ajudar também.

Comment: já postei mas depois eliminei porque fica com muito código a pergunta e não é bem recebida pela comunidade

Comment: quando faço `var_dump($sim)` fora do `for` retorna isto `string(2) "Ok"` e não o valor das 23 linhas, mas se fizer dentro do `for`já retorna as 23 linhas, o problema é estar a fazer o `if` fora do `for`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86761/discussion-between-iniciante-and-gabriel-queiroz-schicora).